# Can't show selected value in dropdown bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Below is the example I tried. But I can't see the selected value in dropdown. **In the example, I want to change the value "Foo" to "Bar", But I can't.** what's the problem here?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>LGA Form</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
            $(this).parents(".input-group-btn").find('.btn').text($(this).text());
            $(this).parents(".input-group-btn").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
}); 
 </script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   Foo      
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left">
   <li><a href="#" data-value="bar">Bar</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-value="baz">Baz</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-value="beh">Beh</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code _works_ as designed, but it over-writes the caret span.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/11630/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you're missing a document ready call & the text rather than val call too - have updated below

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".dropdown-menu li a").on('click',function(evt){
        $(this).closest(".input-group-btn").find('.btn').text($(this).data('value'));
   }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to update the button text with the selected drop down value. Please note that according to your question, you want to change "Foo" to "Bar", however your value is not "Bar", but "bar". I am retrieving the value using `.data('value')`. If you wanted to retrieve the text, you would use `.text()`.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/o9jL71Lv/)

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
     var btn = $(this).parents(".input-group-btn").find('.btn'); //get button
     var ddValue = $(this).data('value'); //get selected value
     var ddText = $(this).text(); //get selected text
     btn.text(ddValue); //set button text to selected value
 });
```